# How do I keep a user logged in my website?

Tags: javascript, authentication, facebook-login

I am using Facebook API to log in a user. It logs in a user successfully.

But whenever I refresh the website or close it then reopen it logs out automatically. I don't need that I want a user logged in until he himself logs out of my website. How do I do it?

This is my code:

```
function statusChangeCallback(response) {


    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        setElements(true);
        console.log('Logged in');
        instaInfo();
    } else {
        setElements(false);
        console.log('not logged in');
    }
}

function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
}

function setElements(isLoggedIn) {
    if (isLoggedIn) {
        document.querySelector('#fb-btn').style.display = 'none';
        document.querySelector('.logout').style.display = 'block';
        document.querySelector('.navigation').style.display = 'block';
        document.querySelector('.nav-main').style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.querySelector('#container').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.querySelector('#fb-btn').style.display = 'block';
        document.querySelector('.logout').style.display = 'none';
        document.querySelector('.navigation').style.display = 'none';
        document.querySelector('.nav-main').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.querySelector('#container').style.display = 'none';
    }
}

document.querySelector('.logout').addEventListener('click', () => {
    FB.logout(function() {
        setElements(false);    
        console.log('Logged Out!');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the facebook documentation:

> While you can call FB.getLoginStatus any time (for example, when the
> user tries to take a social action), most social apps need to know the
> user's status as soon as possible after the page loads. In this case,
> rather than calling FB.getLoginStatus explicitly, it is possible to
> check the user's status by setting status: true when you call FB.init.
>
> To receive the response of this call, you must subscribe to the
> auth.statusChange event. The response object passed by this event is
> identical to that which would be returned by calling FB.getLoginStatus
> explicitly.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

It might just be that you're running into a problem with the asynchronous nature of javascript in your code example. Have you checked what your call on getLoginStatus actually returns?

Comment: The getLoginStatus returns me accessToken and expiration date.

Comment: Then I'd guess your call to the api takes too long and the code you have runs before it is completed. Naively you could put it in a setTimeout() but have a look at rxjs, it's a better way to handle asynchronicity: https://rxjs.dev/

Comment: Ok which part of code do I put in setTimeout().

Comment: That would probably be either your call of checkLoginState() or the code inside that function, but like I said, there are better ways which you should consider.

Comment: okay, I'll have a look at rxjs.dev

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the browser's localStorage (it' s a method of the *window* object) to keep the data even after reloading the page or even after closing the window.

Take a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: I have tried using localStorage but it didn't quite work well.